# Debian Live - modprobe failed to bring up Broadcom ethernet interfaces

Tags: linux, debian, ethernet, broadcom, modprobe

I have a Dell 710 with Quad Bcom NetExtreme 5709s.  In the name of expediency, I'm trying to boot off the Squeeze live CD, but the Broadcom drivers are in non-free, so they don't come up when you boot.

No problem, I think to myself.  I will sneaker-net the bnx2-firmware deb and all is good.

I can see the interfaces in `lspci`, I have unpacked the deb and successfully executed `modprobe bnx2`; however I still can't see the interfaces in `ip link show`.  What else should I do to bring these interfaces up without a reboot?

### EDIT

I have old entries in `/var/log/kern.log` about the failure to load `bnx2` at boot, but the modprobe completes successfully with no other log entries...

```
$ lsmod | grep bnx
bnx2                   57385  0
```

Comment: Does loading the module produce anything in `/var/log/kern.log`? (They usually do.)

Comment: @Gilles, I have `bnx2` failure messages in `kern.log` while booting, but nothing with a timestamp around the time of my `modprobe`.  I expect the messages on boot because the firmware isn't there.

Comment: And you did `rmmod bnx2` before `modprobe bnx2`, right? As well as `rmmod` of any auxiliary module it might be using?

Comment: @Gilles, `rmmod bnx2` and another `modprobe` worked.  Thank you, please repost your answer below so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firmware must be present at the time you load the driver. So be sure to unload the module and reload it:

```
 # <install firmware>
 rmmod bnx2
 modprobe bnx2
```

For some drivers (I don't know about this one), you may need to unload auxiliary modules that it's using. `lsmod | grep bnx2` will show what modules `bnx2` uses. Call `rmmod` on all of them in reverse dependency order.

Most modules emit some log messages when they're loaded and they find a potential device, sometimes even if they don't find a potential device. These logs would be on `/var/log/kern.log`, at least on Debian and Ubuntu.

Comment: I should have thought to remove the module...  I am getting rusty